# Swift: How to scale image on LaunchScreen for iPad

Tags: ios, swift, image, ipad, scale

Is there a function in the attributes inspector or elsewhere that allows you to scale an image on the LaunchScreen.xib so that it looks good both on iPhone and iPad? I know how to do it with fonts, but images?

Comment: Can't you use Auto Layout in the .xib file and place the image in an asset catalogue with 2x and 3x resolutions?

Comment: sounds like a plan. auto layout is checked in xib. i dragged 'image view' onto the launchscreen.xib and dropped a round image.png in the asset catalogue, on the same level as the appicon folder. is it okay to drop higher resolutions there as well or do i need to fill them into the boxes of launchimage (where all the different formats are)? and when i double the resolution of my image in photoshop will that count as a 2x or is there a special website that generates these files? (as you can probably tell, i'm new to this...)

Comment: I'll post an answer below…

Comment: I found a way to generate the files with Prepo. But your answer will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using Asset Catalogues and Auto Layout.

### Auto Layout

First, drag an image view onto the canvas (should be a square if "use size classes is checked"). This is where your image will go. To dynamically change the size of the image, we will simply give the image view some rules about how it should lay itself out. Control-drag from the image view to the view behind it. If you do this in the canvas, the visible constraint options will correspond to the general direction you drug the connection line to. If you control-drag between the elements in the project outline, you will get all options. You will need to set enough constraints so that no sizing is ambiguous and no constraint lines are red.

[image: Adding constraints]

You can inspect and edit the constraints in the Size Inspector.

[image: Inspecting constraints]

If at any point and time you have orange constraints and Xcode gives you a warning saying frames will be different at runtime, simply select the image and update frames from the menu popping out of the right-most icon on the bottom-right of the canvas (triangle in-between two lines).

[image: Updating frames]

By the way, double-clicking any of these blue constraints lets you edit them.

[image: Editing Constraints]

### Asset Catalogues

Now, you just need to add the image to the image view. First, navigate to the Asset Catalogue (.xcassets file) you like to use. Click the plus button at the bottom and add a "New Image Set". In the first box you should drag the image that you would like, whatever size you want (do test). @2x is double the pixel width and height and @3x is likewise triple. These higher resolutions will take up the same amount of physical space but look better with the higher pixel density retina displays.

At this point, your launch screen should look good on any sized device, and on iPad Split Screen if you choose to support it.

Here's an [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Iconography.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH59-SW1) on Icons and Graphics.

Comment: Very comprehensive guide - my image looks good now. Thank you!

Comment: One more question: Do I have to provide extra LaunchImages/Splashscreens in the catalogue section when I already have the other one as Image Set in three versions?

Comment: Nope. As an alternative to Auto Layout in a .xib file, you could opt to use an iOS Launch Image set instead, but not both. The General settings of your app target include an option for using an Asset Catalogue instead of the xib. That refers to having a Launch Image Set in the Catalogue. In short, if you used the xib, you shouldn't need a Launch Image Set.